# How do I train the OSX Auto-Correct to fix my particular brand of typos?

Tags: macos, spell-check

I'm proud of my typos.  They are like the proof that I can type way too fast, probably faster than I can think.

I love the auto-correct feature, once I got used to not going "AH! Typo! *furious backspacing* Retype correctly!"

I have one beef though. It seems that the typos I make are nonstandard enough that about 50% of the time, Auto-Correct chooses the wrong word. This irritates me even more than making a typo in the first place. It seems to happen often with double letter endings where I miss one, but that's certainly not the only case.

Example: When typing the word 'will' I often type 'wil', I have no idea why. Auto-Correct zaps this to 'ail'. So then, instead of backspace, type another L, space, keep going, I have to delete the entire wrong word.

The reason I am asking here is that **I don't want to add misspelled words to the dictionary, I want to train the behavior of the Auto-Correct engine itself so that it's more accurate to my typos as opposed to the 'standard' ones.**

Is this possible? I can't imagine that there's no capability for learning in that algorithm. I dream of a time when I can just mash away at the keyboard, and the computer just knows what I mean and records my rhoughts (There's another one: it gets instantly set to 'roughest' instead of 'thoughts') accordingly.  If auto-correct can be trained, that takes us a lot closer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an easy fix for this.
Open System Preferences. In the window that appears, select keyboard. Click the tab labeled "text". In this window, you can set specific misspelled words to correct to the word you want. Hope this helped!

Comment: This tab has since moved to Language and Text in OSX 10.8, but this does work.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, and in 10.9 the tab is *updated*, so it technically moved to keyboard and not the other way around. Lol have a nice day :)